# simple html anchor tag is not redirecting on click

Tags: html, anchor

It just HTML part of my PHP code which gives listing of products. I want the product image to be clickable which redirect to product detail page, but it seems that anchor tag is not working.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<a href="/ProductUrl" class="grid-item">   //This code is basically under a loop which results in 6 products

      <img src="/img1.jpg" alt="gem">

</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Curious, why would you put a block element (`div`) inside an inline element (`a`)? That's really broken HTML and some browsers might fright upon it. Can't you get rid of the `div` inside the `a` and apply the `grid-item` class on the `a`?

Comment: hey methode, I had edited my code but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the html document, view its page source, click the link of the href, check if its there. It might be in the wrong url.

Comment: I did this and the url is correct. It is working. It redirects to page source of the url.

Answer (score 0):

@TheWell has given a good solution. Also you can give url like this,

```
<a href="../ProductUrl">
```